# Customize storm-react-diagrams with react-vis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-vis

I have a customized storm-react-diagram Node:

```
this.engine.registerNodeFactory(new ExampleNodeFactory());

const node2 = new ExampleNodeModel();
const port2 = node2.addPort( new ExamplePortModel("left") );
```

My render method within the Widget looks like this:

```
render() { 
    return (
        <div className="grid-node" style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '140px'}}>            
            <ExampleIcon style={{width: '80px', height: '80px', position: 'relative', color: '#0d84b7'}} />            
        </div>
    );
}
```

My question: Is it possible to add a react-vis gauge diagram element to my customized Node?

The result would be the rendered Node with the react-vis gauge element surrounding my Node.

Wasn't able to figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be using the right library for your use case. React-vis is a library for doing html and dom manipulation using react on the browser. It sounds like you are shooting for a react-native application, which i would suggest using something like victory-native for (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native).